# Kafka Connect for GCP PubSub using Strimzi Operator

Tags: apache-kafka, strimzi

i have setup kafka cluster using the Strimzi Operator v0.38 and Kafka Cluster 3.5.1 in my GKE cluster. I am now in confusion how to setup the YAML file to build the Kafka Connector so i can pull the message in GCP Pub Sub topic. Is there anyone that can help me? Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need first to deploy a kafka connect using Strimzi CRD file of kind **KafkaConnect** and then configure the PubSub Sink Connector.

See [an example of deploying a sink mongo connector with Strimzi](https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2023/03/29/deploy-kafka-connect-container-using-strimzi#validate_the_mongodb_content), you just need to change the sink mongo connector to PubSub Sink Connector with his [configs](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/gcp-pubsub/current/overview.html)

Comment: hi Sara, thanks for your help. I am quite understand the idea that you give me but still find it hard to build based on the example. perhaps do you have another references that i can use? sorry for the trouble

Comment: Hi @Melvin, What is that you found less clear ? Are you new to Strimzi Operator or to Kafka connector, so I can explain more ?

Comment: Hi @Sara, yes just last week i learned about Strimzi Operator and Kafka Connector. My main objective is to build a security monitoring tool using elasticsearch as log data storage which pulled from GCP PubSub Topic. As our environment is using Kubernetes, i realize that Kafka Connector is required but i still having the trouble to understand the basic configuration i should build on the yaml file in order to receive the log data from GCP PubSub.